# OR-ing LIKE queries in Supabase with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, supabase

I'm trying to run an OR LIKE query across multiple columns in Supabase using Angular but can't find details of the syntax anywhere.

I can do:

```
await this.supabase
.from('post')
.select('title, body')
.like('title', '%'+str+'%')
```

which works fine, and I've seen the .OR syntax in the documentation:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select('name')
  .or('id.gt.3,and(id.eq.1,name.eq.Afghanistan)')
```

but I can't combine the two, any combination I've tried doesn't work. Does anyone know if this is supported and if so what the expression should be? Thanks.

Comment: This is not supported as I cannot find anything like this in the Postgrest docs which is what this querying syntax is using under the hood. https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/tables_views.html?highlight=ilike#operator-modifiers